# Finding volume using integration

Tags: integration

> Find the volume generated when the region bounded by $y=x^3$ and the $x$-axis between $x=2$ and $x=7$ is rotated through $360^{\circ}$ about the $x$-axis.

Here is my attempt is this correct?
\begin{align*}
  y &= x^3 \, , \; 2\le x\le7 \\
  V &= \int_a^b \pi y^2 \, dx \\
  &= \int_2^7\pi(x^3)^2 \, dx \\
  &= \pi\int_2^7x^6 \, dx \\
  &= \pi \left[ \frac{x^7}7 \right]_2^7 \\
  &= \pi \left( 117649-\frac{128}{7} \right) \\
  &= \frac{823415\pi}{7}
\end{align*}

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yup it's correct: [verification](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+pi*x%5E6+from+2+to+7)

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rotate+y%3Dx%5E3+around+x+axis+from+x+%3D+2+to+x+%3D+7) is even better.